# Macro is deleting what I want to keep

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro, but it´s deleting the rows that I want to keep, based on a number(the number of the row) it has to keep that, it can move to another sheet, but everything that I try it just moves the last match or deletes every row that I want to keep.
[What happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSiiX.jpg)

```
Sub KeepRows()
    Dim x As Range, u As Range
    Dim y As String

    With Sheets("Sheetwithnumberrow")
        Set x = .Range(.Cells(2, "H"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each u In x
        If u.Text = "keep row" Then
            Sheets("SheetthatIwannaClean").Select
            y = u.Offset(0, -1)
            Rows(y).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: I put the image of what is happening, I tried to move to another sheet instead of cleaning the contents, bus only move the last row.

```
Product ROW Instruction ROW Instruction
1          6    keep row    6   keep row
2          15   keep row    15  keep row
3          18   Try Next    17  keep row
4          24   keep row    24  keep row
5          28   keep row    28  keep row
```

The logic it´s like thig, it goes at the row, if the instruction is to keep, has to keep, and go to next line. But the problem is, that the code its deleting the row.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Try `For Each u In x` instead of `For Each c In x`. If you were to include `Option Explicit` before the sub then you are more likely to catch such errors yourself. Also, change `Sheets("SheetthatIwannaClean").Select` to `Sheets("SheetthatIwannaClean").Activate` (although you can remove this line altogether).

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I made the mistake writing here, In the code it U.

Comment: If you want to keep the row, then change the condition: `If u.Text <> "keep row" Then`?

Comment: It sounds like a strange setup. Therefore, I would like to verify: there really is in column `G` in each row and this number in column `G` indicates a row which should get deleted? Or is it actually, that you want to keep the rows in which `keep row` is? In that case you'd have to change `Rows(y).ClearContents` to `.Rows(u.Row).ClearContents`.

Comment: There are 2 sheets, on the second one, on the column G, it´s stored the number of the row that I wanna keep on sheet 1. The macro is doing the exactly opposite of what i want. I am starting to learn, and it´s the far that I got, and If i try to move, instead of using clear, it only moves the last row.

Comment: If I use <> give a error on the line y = u.Offset(0, -1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub KeepRows()
    Dim x As Range, u As Range
    Dim y As String

    With Sheets("Sheetwithnumberrow")
        Set x = .Range(.Cells(2, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each u In x
        If u.Text <> "keep row" Then Sheets("SheetthatIwannaClean").Rows(u.Offset(0, -1)).EntireRow.ClearContents
    Next u
End Sub
```